# How do I check that my branching is valid

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to follow a good `Gitflow` process with my development. I have a master and a develop branch right now. I have not been creating branches off `develop`, for features, because I am foolish. I have taken an existing code base, and added it to git, and I thought I started with `master`. And then branched off master to create a `develop` branch.

I've been doing this command-line. To learn. (I created the branches, though, in Azure Dev Ops).

However, I now want to create a release branch, and make my automated builds send builds to my test environment, when ever I do a pull request into release. So I opened SourceTree (As I can't see a nice representation in Azureo Dev Ops.

[image]

This doesn't seem right. I cannot understand why my selected branch, which I think is the blue line, and is `develop`, starts before `master`.

By looking at that image, is there anyway to tell that master is my `HEAD`? `origin`? And that develop is tracking off it?

And to create a `release` branch - do I just create a new branch off `develop`? Because then I need to **merge** into `master` when I do the release, right? Will that be OK if I am branch off develop? I'm worried I have started with a mistake somewhere, but not sure how to confirm that I am on track for a good git flow pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By looking at that image, is there anyway to tell that master is my HEAD? origin? And that develop is tracking off it?

HEAD is the commit you are on now. So right now `develop` is your HEAD. You are on `develop`. If you double-click `master`, you'll be on `master` and `master` will be your HEAD.

> This doesn't seem right. I cannot understand why my selected branch, which I think is the blue line, and is develop, starts before master.

You seem to think that a branch is an entire chain of commits unified as having a color in the chart, and one chain somehow assuming primacy over the others.  Not so.

A branch is merely the name of one commit. At the moment, `develop` is the name of a commit that we can't see (you've scrolled it off the screen). That commit had a parent, which has a parent, which has a parent... leading back in time to the very first parent, "Added README".

The fact that you were on `master` at the time you made that commit is *irrelevant*; that fact does not magically mean that "Added README" is "on" `master` in some special sense. It *is* "on" `master`, in the sense that `master` is the name of a commit ("Merged PR 1") which has a parent, which has a parent, ... leading back to "Added README". But it is "on" `develop` in the very same sense; the color is arbitrary, and makes sense given the fact you are on `develop` at the moment. If you switch to `master`, as I just suggested, the colors will change and the history of `master` leading back to the first commit will be emphasised.

> And to create a release branch - do I just create a new branch off develop?

I wouldn't. If you're going to have a separate release branch, rather than releasing off of `master`, I'd suggest that you create `release` off the very first commit. So you merge `develop` into `master` periodically, and `master` into `release`. That way, the whole history of `release` consists of merges, and every merge onto `release` means, "This was a state of `master` that we actually released."

Comment: Brilliant, @matt- That's is extremely helpful! Thanks.